# SonarQube Scanner + Jenkins + Maven = java.lang.ClassFormatError

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube, pmd, sonarqube5.3

I were using SonarQube 5.4 with Jenkins and MAven build (using Prepare sonarqube environement, I could inject environment variables).
Then I decided to upgrade to 5.6.3LTS (in order to upgrade latest (6.2)) but my build doesn't work anymore :S
I got this stacktrace and I don't understand what's wrong...

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project sopra-banking-framework-superpom: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/metamodel/Attribute$PersistentAttributeType
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.2/sonar-maven-plugin-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.2/maven-dependency-tree-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.8/sonar-scanner-api-2.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/D:/m2repo/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/D:/m2repo/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[JENKINS] Archiving C:\Jenkins\workspace\SBF-trunk-deploy\workspace\sopra-banking-framework-superpom\sopra-banking-framework\pom.xml to com.sopra.banking/sopra-banking-framework/1.13.2-SNAPSHOT/sopra-banking-framework-1.13.2-SNAPSHOT.pom
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
```

My SonarScanner is automatically installed (v2.8) and my maven runner is set at latest (v3.2).

Feel free to ask me anything !

Edit 1 :
This is the full log :

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project sopra-banking-framework-superpom: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/metamodel/Attribute$PersistentAttributeType
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2
[ERROR] strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
[ERROR] urls[0] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.2/sonar-maven-plugin-3.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[1] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.2/maven-dependency-tree-2.2.jar
[ERROR] urls[2] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
[ERROR] urls[3] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
[ERROR] urls[4] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[5] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
[ERROR] urls[6] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
[ERROR] urls[7] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.8/sonar-scanner-api-2.8.jar
[ERROR] urls[8] = file:/D:/m2repo/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
[ERROR] urls[9] = file:/D:/m2repo/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar
[ERROR] Number of foreign imports: 1
[ERROR] import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] -----------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar (default-cli) on project sopra-banking-framework-superpom: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/metamodel/Attribute$PersistentAttributeType
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.2/sonar-maven-plugin-3.2.jar
urls[1] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.2/maven-dependency-tree-2.2.jar
urls[2] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[3] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
urls[4] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
urls[5] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
urls[6] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
urls[7] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.8/sonar-scanner-api-2.8.jar
urls[8] = file:/D:/m2repo/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
urls[9] = file:/D:/m2repo/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.jvnet.hudson.maven3.launcher.Maven33Launcher.main(Maven33Launcher.java:129)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Launcher.java:330)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:238)
    at jenkins.maven3.agent.Maven33Main.launch(Maven33Main.java:176)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:133)
    at hudson.maven.Maven3Builder.call(Maven3Builder.java:68)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:153)
    at hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:50)
    at hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:336)
    at hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:68)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-cli of goal org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/metamodel/Attribute$PersistentAttributeType
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.2/sonar-maven-plugin-3.2.jar
urls[1] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.2/maven-dependency-tree-2.2.jar
urls[2] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[3] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
urls[4] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
urls[5] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
urls[6] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
urls[7] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.8/sonar-scanner-api-2.8.jar
urls[8] = file:/D:/m2repo/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
urls[9] = file:/D:/m2repo/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:183)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 31 more
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginContainerException: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2:sonar: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/metamodel/Attribute$PersistentAttributeType
-----------------------------------------------------
realm =    plugin>org.codehaus.mojo:sonar-maven-plugin:3.2
strategy = org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.strategy.SelfFirstStrategy
urls[0] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonarsource/scanner/maven/sonar-maven-plugin/3.2/sonar-maven-plugin-3.2.jar
urls[1] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/apache/maven/shared/maven-dependency-tree/2.2/maven-dependency-tree-2.2.jar
urls[2] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-component-annotations/1.5.5/plexus-component-annotations-1.5.5.jar
urls[3] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/eclipse/aether/aether-util/0.9.0.M2/aether-util-0.9.0.M2.jar
urls[4] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-sec-dispatcher/1.4/plexus-sec-dispatcher-1.4.jar
urls[5] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonatype/plexus/plexus-cipher/1.4/plexus-cipher-1.4.jar
urls[6] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/codehaus/plexus/plexus-utils/3.0.22/plexus-utils-3.0.22.jar
urls[7] = file:/D:/m2repo/org/sonarsource/scanner/api/sonar-scanner-api/2.8/sonar-scanner-api-2.8.jar
urls[8] = file:/D:/m2repo/commons-lang/commons-lang/2.6/commons-lang-2.6.jar
urls[9] = file:/D:/m2repo/com/google/code/findbugs/jsr305/2.0.3/jsr305-2.0.3.jar
Number of foreign imports: 1
import: Entry[import  from realm ClassRealm[maven.api, parent: null]]

-----------------------------------------------------

    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:181)
    ... 32 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/persistence/metamodel/Attribute$PersistentAttributeType
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.PMDASMClassLoader.loadClass(PMDASMClassLoader.java:65)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.populateType(ClassTypeResolver.java:664)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.visit(ClassTypeResolver.java:179)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTImportDeclaration.jjtAccept(ASTImportDeclaration.java:62)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.AbstractJavaNode.childrenAccept(AbstractJavaNode.java:55)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:9)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.JavaParserVisitorAdapter.visit(JavaParserVisitorAdapter.java:136)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.ClassTypeResolver.visit(ClassTypeResolver.java:170)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.ast.ASTCompilationUnit.jjtAccept(ASTCompilationUnit.java:42)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.TypeResolutionFacade.initializeWith(TypeResolutionFacade.java:17)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.AbstractJavaHandler$5.start(AbstractJavaHandler.java:88)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.usesTypeResolution(SourceCodeProcessor.java:127)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSource(SourceCodeProcessor.java:142)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:76)
    at net.sourceforge.pmd.SourceCodeProcessor.processSourceCode(SourceCodeProcessor.java:43)
    at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdTemplate.process(PmdTemplate.java:82)
    at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executeRules(PmdExecutor.java:120)
    at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.executePmd(PmdExecutor.java:90)
    at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdExecutor.execute(PmdExecutor.java:75)
    at org.sonar.plugins.pmd.PmdSensor.analyse(PmdSensor.java:67)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.executeSensor(SensorsExecutor.java:58)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.SensorsExecutor.execute(SensorsExecutor.java:50)
    at org.sonar.batch.phases.AbstractPhaseExecutor.execute(AbstractPhaseExecutor.java:83)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ModuleScanContainer.doAfterStart(ModuleScanContainer.java:192)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scan(ProjectScanContainer.java:241)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:236)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:234)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.scanRecursively(ProjectScanContainer.java:234)
    at org.sonar.batch.scan.ProjectScanContainer.doAfterStart(ProjectScanContainer.java:226)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.ScanTask.execute(ScanTask.java:47)
    at org.sonar.batch.task.TaskContainer.doAfterStart(TaskContainer.java:86)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.startComponents(ComponentContainer.java:142)
    at org.sonar.core.platform.ComponentContainer.execute(ComponentContainer.java:127)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrap.GlobalContainer.executeTask(GlobalContainer.java:106)
    at org.sonar.batch.bootstrapper.Batch.executeTask(Batch.java:119)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.batch.BatchIsolatedLauncher.execute(BatchIsolatedLauncher.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.internal.IsolatedLauncherProxy.invoke(IsolatedLauncherProxy.java:60)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy57.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.doExecute(EmbeddedScanner.java:233)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.api.EmbeddedScanner.runAnalysis(EmbeddedScanner.java:151)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.bootstrap.ScannerBootstrapper.execute(ScannerBootstrapper.java:78)
    at org.sonarsource.scanner.maven.SonarQubeMojo.execute(SonarQubeMojo.java:122)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 32 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginContainerException
```

Comment: FWIW - which version of JVM do you use? Java 8 is required starting from SonarQube 5.6. Did you tried other projects - do they have the same behavior? Also could you please provide a bigger log with a bit less clipping?

Comment: JVM : 8u92, on my other project, I use old behavior with login/password on other project and it works but now I'd like to use authentification token, new from 5.3+

Comment: So it seems that you don't have same issue with other projects, hence this has nothing to do with upgrade. And actually seems (looking at "net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.PMDASMClassLoader" from the bigger excerpt of log) that problem is caused by inability of PMD to deal with dependencies of your project. And therefore nothing to do with "authentication token". For a very long time there are native SonarQube rules replacing PMD rules, so you can consider stop usage of PMD to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Yes, you were right, it was a trouble with PMD plugin. I uninstalled it and everything went good.

Comment: Cool! I convert this into an answer, so you can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems (looking at `net.sourceforge.pmd.lang.java.typeresolution.PMDASMClassLoa‌​der`) that problem is caused by inability of PMD to deal with dependencies of your project. For a very long time there are native SonarQube rules replacing PMD rules, so you can consider stop usage of PMD to get rid of this problem.